# VSCode: Not work quick-access for running apps with Spring Boot Tools

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

## Environment

- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- Visual Studio Code: 1.26.1
- Spring Boot Tools: 0.5.0

## I want help on how to use this feature

Spring Boot Tools plugin.
I would like to use the function of `Quick-access for running apps` .
I confirm this function at the following site.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Pivotal.vscode-spring-boot#user-content-quick-access-for-running-apps

## Problem

1. Endpoint navigation good works!
2. But, when I select an endpoint from the navigation, an error is displayed.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa0QM.png
   This output mean `'hello' is not open:resource is not avaliable.` .

## Question

The following information is on the site.

> // shows all request mappings of all running Spring Boot apps and opens  a browser for the selected endpoint

Do I need to set something to display the browser?
Can I check the detailed problem contents from a log somewhere?

### Supplement

I checked https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc 
I don't create `spring-tools-4` tag.